# IKEv2 VPN on macOs 10.12 Sierra

Tags: vpn, macos

When I try to configure an IKEv2 VPN on macOs Sierra the following errors occur:

```
nesessionmanager    Failed to find the VPN app for plugin type com.apple.neplugin.IKEv2
neagent Failed to process IKE SA Init packet
```

From the first line it seems it's not supported at all.

Have you experienced the same issue?

Comment: Are you polling to find out if other people are having this problem, or are you looking for assistance in resolving it? The former is off-topic.

Comment: @tubedogg The latter, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation, setting server-side in ipsec.conf:

```
 leftsendcert=always
```

solved the problem.

From ipsec.conf documentation:

> left|rightsendcert = never | no | ifasked | always | yes
>
> Accepted values are never or no, always or yes, and ifasked, the
>   latter meaning that  the peer must send a certificate request (CR)
>   payload in order to get a certificate in return.

Moreover, I had to add to the Keychain the root certificate and trust it in order to validate the certificate sent by the server and I read that if you have intermediate certificates you have to trust them too.

Comment: For me, manually trusting the root certificate solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is not my case :(

Answer (score 0):

May be related to known bug https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/6082 and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7453073

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Please summarize what the link offers, details on a known bug, and any fixes possible.